# Xdebug: Warning: Failed loading Zend extension 'xdebug'

Tags: php, warnings, xdebug

I'm having trouble installing xdebug on windows. I followed the instructions of xdebug wizard but it keeps giving me the warning

> Warning: Failed loading Zend extension 'xdebug' (tried: C:/laragon/bin/php/php-8.2.1-nts-Win32-vs16-x64/ext\xdebug (Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato), C:/laragon/bin/php/php-8.2.1-nts-Win32-vs16-x64/ext\php_xdebug.dll (Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato)) in Unknown on line 0

I have php 8.2.1. These are the instructions:

> ### Instructions
>
> 1. Download [php_xdebug-3.2.0-8.2-vs16-nts-x86_64.dll](https://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-3.2.0-8.1-vs16-x86_64.dll)
> 2. Move the downloaded file to C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.2.1-nts-Win32-vs16-x64\ext, and rename it to `php_xdebug.dll`
> 3. Update `C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.2.1-nts-Win32-vs16-x64\php.ini` and add the line:
>    `zend_extension = xdebug`
> 4. Restart the Apache Webserver

I also tried changing the php version to 8.1.10 but it keeps giving me the same warning

EDIT:
I used the full path

> zend_extension =
> C:/laragon/bin/php/php-8.2.1-nts-Win32-vs16-x64/ext/php_xdebug.dll

and now give me this error

> Failed loading
> C:/laragon/bin/php/php-8.2.1-nts-Win32-vs16-x64/ext/php_xdebug.dll

Comment: Could you check that you have the right dll version - TS or NTS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `/` the wrong way around: `php-8.2.1-nts-Win32-vs16-x64/ext\php_xdebug.dll` — that is either because you have an `extension_dir` setting that is wrong, or you used `zend_extension = \xdebug` or something like that.

I would recommend in this case, to use the full path in the `zend_extension` line:

```
zend_extension = C:/laragon/bin/php/php-8.2.1-nts-Win32-vs16-x64/ext/php_xdebug.dll
```